# Can the government change a plea offer based on a dismiss motion the defense files?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, federal-courts, us-federal-government

Suppose you are accused of something that doesn't make sense or shouldn't be placed on you based on jurisdiction, and decide with your retained defense attorney to file a motion to dismiss those charges.

If the government has already offered you a plea offer quite early on, with no jail time/small fine, can they make that offer less favorable just because you filed that motion?

They were annoyed and "mad" that you've bothered to file a motion, so they screw you over with an increased sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A prosecutor has very broad discretion to offer and rescind a plea agreement, subject to Federal Rules of Criminal Procedure [Rule 11](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcrmp/rule_11). [This note](https://www.bja.gov/Publications/PleaBargainingResearchSummary.pdf) gathers together sources that have studied the effect of this discretion. If you reject an offer, then the offer isn't there anymore. Either side can withdraw from a bargain until the judge accepts it.

Comment: @use6726 so if they do retract the offer and modify it accordingly since you filed the motion, will they consider the fact that if you've already been denied bail and time you've already spent in prison (sometimes months)?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to know in general what a prosecutor *will* do; they can. The main motivation is getting a conviction at the lowest prosecutorial cost. Time spent isn't a fact that can be used at trial to secure a conviction, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @Unicorn13601 In other words, yes, they can do what you propose in the OP or pretty much anything else (other than withdraw an accepted plea bargain which is a more complex area of law).

Comment: Theoretically, they could even withdraw an offer that was accepted by the defendant, as long as it hasn't been accepted by the judge yet. (Doing so defeats the whole point of plea agreements, though, so it wouldn't be in their interest unless circumstances change dramatically.)

Comment: @user6726 I just want to confirm. Suppose you've already spent half in jail, cause you were denied bail. The prosecutors are aware of this, so when they make the plea offer, they purposely extend the jail time because they want you to be in jail for x amount of time even after you plead guilty, regardless of the time already served. I'm assuming this could happen? Maybe a new question is in order.

Comment: @ohwilleke usually the new offer would be alittle bit harsher right? Would it be EVEN worse if you were to lose that motion to dismiss?

Comment: @Unicorn13601 This is entirely fact specific. There are all manner of reasons that plea bargain offers can change.